# change the backcolor of a node in tree panel

Tags: extjs

Here i am working on a use case where i am searching a node in the tree and then i want to mark the search result with some color.

i am able to search a node in a tree by using findChild API , it returns me the searched node from the tree , but i am not able to mark the node with some back color , just for identification purpose.

i tried the following

```
searchResult.cls = 'bg_TreeNodeColor';
```

and the css is

```
.bg_TreeNodeColor
{
    background-color:#FF0000 !important;
}
```

anybody has any idea on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
searchResult.set('cls', 'bg_TreeNodeColor');
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michel it works , but i used cls instead of iconCls , iconCls changes only for the icon. anyways thanks once again :-)